# How to program enc28j60??

Tags: ethernet, atmel, enc28j60

I read enc28j60 is unprogrammable directly from the computer but it has registers that I can program so how can I excactly do this.. is it programmed from the mcu connected to it through spi or is there another method?? Also must I connect alogic level shifter 3.3v-》5v from enc28j60 to atmel mcu even if I connect the enc28j60 itself to 5v power supply? If so how to make a logic level shifter circuit myself instead of buying one? Thabks in advance

Comment: Please do a little proof-reading and formatting to make this question more readable.

Comment: And give the datasheet a read.

Comment: Talking about "programming" the ENC28J60 doesn't really make a lot of sense. It's a device, not a controller. You program *something else*, like a microcontroller, to use it.

Comment: @duskwuff how can I then acess the registers in it and change the bits values without programming

Comment: This is going nowhere. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect the ENC28J60 directly to a 5V supply you will likely destroy it (absolute maximum is 3.6V- see the data sheet ratings). The relevant inputs, however are 5V tolerant so you should not need a voltage level translator.

The registers etc. are all controlled through an external MCU- the chip has no internal non-volatile memory so it must be set up each time the power is cycled.